# Rake Tests: Gem Load Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I defined a simple rake task for running my ruby tests but have the problem that rake doesn't load a gem with the version defined in Gemfile. It get a `Gem::LoadError`. Is there a way to tell rake which gem version to use?

Here are the gems installed on my system:

```
addressable (2.2.6, 2.2.4)
bundler (1.0.15)
libarchive (0.1.2)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdf (0.3.3)
```

And this is my GemFile:

```
source :rubygems

gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.0'
gem 'rdf', '0.3.3'
gem 'addressable', '2.2.4'
gem 'libarchive', '0.1.2'
```

Here the rake task:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

task :default => [:test]

desc "Run basic tests"
Rake::TestTask.new do |test|
  test.libs << "test"
  test.test_files = Dir["test/test_*.rb"]
  test.verbose = true
end
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
/Users/dummy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1612:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rdf-0.3.3, because addressable-2.2.6 conflicts with addressable (= 2.2.4) (Gem::LoadError)
```

I can solve the problem by uninstalling `addressable 2.2.6` but I need the never version of that gem for another project.

Another solution could be to use rvm gemsets. But isn't it simply possible to run rake with a given Gemfile specification?

Thanks

Comment: Does `bundle exec rake <task>` work?

Comment: I set up distinct rvm gemsets for my projects. Now it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Brian's suggestion should indeed to the trick:

```
bundle exec rake <task>
```

Also, partitioning gemsets, using for instance rvm gemsets, would be another option... there shouldn't be a need to uninstall any gem versions.

Another partitioning technique would be to install all gems **inside** the project directory (as opposed to installing them as system gems), using something akin to:

```
bundle install --path=.bundler
```

See http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html for more info.  Note that this latter solution would still require the `bundle exec` approach to avoid the gem conflicts.

Hope this helps,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

using RVM gemsets (http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/) is probably the best way to deal with gem versioning conflicts across projects. For my scenario it works...